# <mvc:resources> how to use the classpath location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources, classpath

I've searched high and low in order to solve this problem, but I can't find a solution.
The problem is as follows:
I have an Spring-mvc webapp build on a Tomcat 7 server - 7.0.12 to be precise - and I'm having trouble getting the `<mvc:resources>` tag to work correct. As you will see below the `<mvc:resources>` works for the old resource folder, but I prefer having the resource folder in the `/WEB-INF/web/` directory.


MediorkoorVOICES-Web-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">        

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.oudejans.mediorkoorvoices.web" /> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/web/resources/"  />  
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/web/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" /> 

    <import resource="web/tiles/web-tiles.xml" />
</beans>
```

folder structure:

```
META-INF
resources (Old resources folder)
    - web
        - images
        - css
            - main.css      
WEB-INF
    - classes
    - lib
    - admin
    - shared
    - web
        - jsp
        - tiles
        - resources (New resources folder i want to access)
            - images
                - banner.png
            - js
            - etc.
```

Now if I wanted to access the old resource folder, the code below would work.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
&
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/oldBanner.png" />
```

But what I would prefer is to do something like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/web/resources/" />
&
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/banner.png" />
```

Can someone explain to me how I do this? I'm fairly new to spring-mvc.

EDIT1: Additional data: I'm using netbeans 7.1.2 and spring-mvc version is 3.1.0 combined with maven.

Below is the Pom.xml

```
<!-- groupId config, etc. removed -->
<!-- packaging type is war -->
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.hibernate.version>3.5.6-Final</org.hibernate.version>
    <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>1.6</netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>    
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT2: I added the complete MediorkoorVOICES-Web-servlet.xml and the web.xml
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/hibernateContext.xml 
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>    

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.err</location>
    </error-page>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MediorkoorVOICES-Web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MediorkoorVOICES-Web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mkvp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MediorkoorVOICES-Admin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MediorkoorVOICES-Admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mkvap</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.err</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

EDIT3: After some more testing I realised that the `<mvc:resources>` tag isn't working at all. (Look at updated folder structure) If I, for instance, do:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/web/" mapping="/resources/**" /> 
&
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css" />click</a>
```

It gives me an 404 as well, while in fact, it should link to the /resources/web/css/main.css file. So all I can think of right now, is that there is some miss configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging and "trying" things, I tried to add the *.css and *.png mapping to the web.xml servlet. Apparently, the resource files weren't mapped to the servlet and therefor couldn't be found. So for everyone with the same mapping as mine, add this to your web.xml **servlet-mapping** tag.

```
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<mvc:resources location="WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

You are referring to the resources using a uri of `/resources/somestatic.gif` but it will be served from `WEB-INF/resources/somestatic.gif`

Comment: Well thats the thing, for some reason either .war, tomcat or spring-mvc resources tag, won't allow me to put my resources in any given subfolder from **/WEB-INF/** or **/META-INF/**. It's almost like those directories are protected from read or something.

Comment: There is a difference in your path and my path, there is no `/WEB-INF/resources/`in my case, it is `WEB-INF/resources/` without the leading `/`, have you tried with this

Comment: yes I have tried without the leading slash, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is totally wrong. Since your resources are in the folder **/WEB-INF/web/resources/** you don't need to specify **classpath:** before it.

So it would be just like below

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/web/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/web/resources/"  />
```

I think that would resolve your problem. Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: sorry still not working. I think its almost like it can't load files in any other subfolder then **/resources/** (old).

Comment: Can you move your resources folder to the root folder of the application and then try with /resources/** in mapping and /resources/ in location. I have this configuration in application which is working fine. I'm not sure about the path inside /WEB-INF/. But it should also work.

Comment: Yeah if I do that it works, but I would prefer my resources in the **/WEB-INF/..** subfolders, so I can keep a better structure. So you think its not possible for me to place it in the **/WEB-INF/** subfolders?

Comment: But if you want to just keep a better structure then you can also do that in the way I have suggested you. in /resources/ folder there can be any number of subfolders and also the url pattern can be the same. I think you should do this way.