# Class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, rest, javabeans

I'm learning REST services by following a book and this is the first exercise which uses beans. I created a bean configuration file (`applicationContext.xml`) and placed it inside a /spring folder, but when I run the application it says it can't find it (as indicated by the following picture):

[image]

Would anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedAdapter.start(JettyEmbeddedAdapter.java:67)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.main(JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 26 more

2017-06-22 17:54:59.076:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/JINK/workspace/SecondExercise/src/main/webapp/},C:\Users\JINK\workspace\SecondExercise\src\main\webapp
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedAdapter.start(JettyEmbeddedAdapter.java:67)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.main(JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.java:42)
Caused by: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedAdapter.start(JettyEmbeddedAdapter.java:67)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.main(JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.java:42)
2017-06-22 17:54:59.196:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8085
------------------------------------------------
Jetty startup finished in 1,4 s.
Used memory: 5,3 MB of 123,0 MB (1,8 GB maximum)
Console available: type "help".
----
```

---

Comment: `/spring` is a source folder. It's part of your source code directory structure. It doesn't exist on the runtime classpath.

Comment: take a look at to this link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120397/mvcresources-how-to-use-the-classpath-location) i hope it help.

Comment: It would be greate if you could provide the stacktrace in the post.

Comment: @Krishna Kuntala: Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the spring folder into the src/main/resources folder in order to have
src/main/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

As your `spring` is a source folder you can refer it directly. The resources in the source directory will be directly added on the classpath.

Change your configuration **web.xml** as:

```
<param-value>
   classpath:applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
```